# Is it possible to trigger a firebase in app messaging from postman to flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-in-app-messaging

I need to trigger the firebase in-app messaging popup from postman like firebase push notification for flutter app. But i cant find proper solution for this. Can anyone suggest me some solution, if it is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-app messaging is always triggered from within the app. There is no way to trigger it externally.

To show a notification via an external trigger, use Firebase Cloud Messaging. There you can:

- either send a notification message, which are handled by the system itself when the user is not actively using the app
- or send a data message, which is always delivered to your application code, so that you can handle the display of the notification yourself.